# Build automation and deployment via team city cloud

Tags: asp.net-core, teamcity

I am using the team city cloud service (beta) and I would like to learn how to do an automated build from Github. My application in asp.net core 3.1 and ef core 3.1.7

For example, my solution layout is as such

[image]

For my application to work I would need to compile build and deploy projects

MisSystem.Dal
MisSystem.Web
MisSystem.Webapi

My question is how would I do that with team city I also have a unit test library that if only the tests all pass should it then deploy out?. I am new to the whole automation thing so if anyone has suggestions for me on a better service or approach.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create a project from an URL. TeamCity auto-detects necessary steps and suggests them to you (".NET" build step with various commands).

I'm sure that build\test command would be auto-detected, not sure about deploy. But it shouldn't be hard to add another step if needed (you would have an example from auto-detected steps).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider looking into using a combination of Team City and Octopus Deploy

[Octopus and Team City, a match made in heaven](https://octopus.com/docs/guides/deploy-aspnet-app/to-iis/using-octopus-onprem-teamcity?__s=xobzf8k3whm63ex2g34c&utm_source=drip&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Onboarding%20Guide&utm_content=Day%201%3A%20Integrating%20Octopus%20Deploy%20into%20your%20CI%2FCD%20pipeline)

Using these tools together you can create a solid CI/CD pipeline to both build/test as well and release (using proper versions) for your application. Octopus has some great guides (and if you find them at all confusing, feedback is welcome!)

Essentially you will want to follow Nadias advice, but I would recommend developing your build process manually to ensure you aren't missing any important steps. From there you would install a plugin for Octopus Deploy.

Both TeamCity and Octopus Deploy have a free tier. You can deploy up to 10 deployment targets with Octopus for free and they provide a fully managed hosted solution or you can download the deployment server and manage things yourself.

One reason I mention Octopus is that they have some thorough tutorials to get you started with the whole setup. But since its a very detailed process to set up, its a bit much to detail in a SO answer. It is better to follow published tutorials. If you need help, there is a great community behind Octopus Deploy on slack, there are youtube videos, and support at Octopus is top-notch. We seriously love helping people deploy software.

**Full Disclosure**: I am a software engineer at Octopus Deploy.

Comment: We used that in one of my past jobs and was a good mix but that was with a dev ops team im just solo on this gig so find the setup of them to be very hard when dealing with a large structure project